# How to calculate 7 day moving average in powerbi with a date filter?

Tags: powerbi

I would like to calculate a 7 day moving average according to a specific time period (2019 data for example). I so far have the following code:

7 days ave = CALCULATE( AVERAGE('Qry data'[Number]), DATESINPERIOD( 'Qry data'[Date], LASTDATE('Qry data'[Date]), -7,DAY))

but I would like to include a filter as this currently selects all data for all dates. I.e. Something like DATEBETWEEN(DATE(2019,01,01), DATE(2019,12,31))

Any help would be hugely appreciated!